# Using a Range Variable

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am having issues when trying to use a Range as a variable.  Keep getting the "Select Method of Range Class Failed" error.  Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

```
Dim OnRent As Workbook
Dim MattFile As Workbook
Dim Rng As Range


Set OnRent = Workbooks("On-Rent 09-22-17.xlsx")
Set MattFile = ThisWorkbook
Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B101")



OnRent.Activate
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("CHKOUT_POOL"). _
    ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("CHKOUT_POOL").CurrentPage _
    = "LOS ANGELES"
Range("B15:L108").Copy
MattFile.Activate
Sheets("LAX Data").Activate
Rng.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 1):

### Problem: Rng.Select only works, if the Rng.Parent is active

The Range.Select method will only work, if the sheet, where the range belongs, is active.

The `Rng` range may not be on the `Sheets("LAX Data")` and by calling `Rng.Select` while another sheet is active, you run into error.

To further explain:

You set the range to
`Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B101")` 'Note: this can be any sheet. The range object stores its position along with the sheet it is from, as a file is defined by a full/absolute path.

Later, when you want to `Rng.Select` you are (can be) on different sheet and the select will not work.

### Do not use Range.Select and Sheet.Activate methods if you dont have to

See [Mats link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410812/using-a-range-variable/46410955#comment79779818_46410955)! Or some of the MANY MANY advice on the net like [Power Excel vba secret, avoid using select](https://www.businessprogrammer.com/power-excel-vba-secret-avoid-using-select/)

### Some code alternative

To demonstrate how this can work, here is some untested code.

```
Sub refreshOnRentForLosAngeles()
    Dim OnRentSheetWithPivots As Worksheet
    Dim Pivot As PivotTable

    Set OnRentSheetWithPivots = Workbooks("On-Rent 09-22-17.xlsx").Sheets(1) 'change to fit
    Set Pivot = OnRentSheetWithPivots.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    Pivot.PivotFields("CHKOUT_POOL").ClearAllFilters
    Pivot.PivotFields("CHKOUT_POOL").CurrentPage = "LOS ANGELES" 'Turn the city into input variable for reusability?

    'The copy source will always be the same? Can u make it dynamic?
    OnRentSheetWithPivots.Range("B15:L108").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LAX Data").Range("B101")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  So even though I am activating the sheet ahead of selecting the Rng cell, it still doesn't know where to put it?  Sounds like the best bet is to keep doing what I am doing and just find and replace the Range every day.  The issue is, I am updating a report daily that is pasting the data from one report to a separate one using 17 different tabs, so that same code above is repeated 17 times, but for different Data tabs.  Figured I would try and find an easy way to change the range output everyday instead of finding and replacing every time.

Comment: @mpthomas1219 **1)** What you are missing is this: Rng variable is stroring **The cells. On The sheet. Only those. It's an object, not a cell address. (read multiple times).** **2)** Dont find and replace hard coded values. Make them variables. For ex. you can make a dropdowns of the city names and the target sheets as well. Then you just select what you need and press a button. **3)** If the paste (destination) cell is always `B101` on every sheet, you can use this  string as an address and combine it with sheet, to make a range. Even better, make a sheet scoped Named range and use that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference range `"B101"` on sheet `"LAX Data"`, you should replace `Rng.Select` with `Range("B101").Select`. this way you will not try to select range which is not on `ActiveSheet` (which is the reason for an error).

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to avoid having to do that.  That is how I have it now, but I am going through 17 different sheets, so I was hoping to only change the Range once instead of having to Find and Replace every time.